# Latex: Running table number

Tags: tables, numbering, counters

There are several tables in my paper, out of which one table is very long and need to be place on landscape page. This is my Table.4 and I want to put it on the last page. For that I used `\setcounter` command to caption it as a Table.4, but how can I arrange previous tables? In my text Table.5 becomes Table.4 etc.

Comment: `\stepcounter{table}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can step the `table` counter and store the current `table` value by defining a new command using `\edef`. This way you ensure that your moved table has the correct number no matter what the other tables are.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{ONE}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{TWO}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{THREE}
\end{table}

% reserve "FOUR"
\stepcounter{table}
\edef\mysavedtablenumber{\thetable}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{FIVE}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{SIX}
\end{table}

% use "FOUR"
\begin{table}[p]
\def\thetable{\mysavedtablenumber}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
TABLE
\end{tabular}
\caption{FOUR}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to remark that this is in my opinion not a good idea. People will search Table.4 between Table.3 and Table.5 and they will be confused by the table not being there. I recommend you to put the table into appendix and number it as Table.A.1 for instance.